# Counter example for equivalent norms.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V=\left \{ (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}\mid sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left | x_n \right | <\infty \right \}$

I want to show that $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert ^{'}=sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n+1\right|!}\}$  and $ \left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert =sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n\right|!}\}$ are not equivalent.

Which means that I need to find a series $v_n\in V$ which contradicts the assumption that 
$c\cdot sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n+1\right|!}\}\leq sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n\right|!}\}\leq C\cdot sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n+1\right|!}\}$  for some $c,C>0$ for all $v_n\in V$

My guess is that I need to somehow build $v_n$ such that $sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n+1\right|!}\} = 0$ and $sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n\right|!}\} > 0$ but I didnt quite manage to create such series..

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general idea is correct, but $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n+1\right|!}\} = 0$ means $\forall n \in \mathbb Z: v_n=0$, so you have the zero vector of your vector space which has norm $0$ in any norm.

To disprove that

$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n\right|!}\}\leq C\cdot \sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\frac{\left|v_{n}\right|}{\left|n+1\right|!}\}$$

holds for any sequence and any given $C>0$, select an $N \in \mathbb Z, N > C$ and consider the vector

$$
v_n=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n=N\\
0 & \text{ otherwise. } \\
\end{cases}
$$

We have $\lVert (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}\rVert=\frac1{N!}$ and $C\lVert (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}\rVert^{'}=\frac{C}{(N+1)!} = \frac1{N!} \frac{C}{N+1} < \lVert (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}\rVert,$

as $\frac{C}{N+1} < 1$ due the choice of $N$.

To disprove the other side of the inequality, the same kind of $(v_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ works, you just need to select a negative $N < -\frac1{c}$.

OTOH, to disprove equivalence you only need to disprove one inequality. But since the index set is $\mathbb Z$, neither inequality holds. If we restrict the indix set to non-negative integers, then obviously $\lVert (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}\rVert^{'} \le \lVert (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}\rVert$ for all sequences.